# How to create function for outputting year end balance and year end earned interest without monthly deposits?

Tags: c++, banking

I am trying to create a function that outputs year end balance and year end earned interest without monthly deposits. I am having a problem with fucntion reportWithoutMonthlyPay. With inputs 1 for investment, 50 for monthly deposit, %5 for annual interest, and 5 for years, it should output:

Year    Year End Balance     Year End Earned Interest

1         $1.05                        $0.05

2         $1.10                        $0.05

3         $1.16                        $0.06

4         $1.22                        $0.06

5         $1.28                        $0.06

Instead it is outputting:

1         $1.34                        $0.06

2         $1.80                        $0.07

3
        $2.42                        $0.10

4         $3.25                        $0.13

5         $4.36                        $0.18

Can someone help me with this?

Here is my code:

```
// BankingApp.cpp : This file contains the 'main' function. Program execution begins and 
ends there.
//

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

class Bank {
public: 
   void dataInput();
   void displayInput();
   void reportWithoutMonthlyPay();
   void reportWithMonthlyPay();

private:
   double investment;
   double deposit;
   int years;
   double interest;
   double monthly_interest;
   double year_end_balance;
   double year_end_interest;
   vector<int> month_numbers;
   vector<int> year_numbers;
 };

 void Bank::dataInput() {
   cout << "Initial Investment Amount: " << endl;
   cin >> investment;
   cout << "Monthly Deposit: " << endl;
   cin >> deposit;
   cout << "Annual Interest: " << endl;
   cin >> interest;
   cout << "Number of years: " << endl;
   cin >> years;
   system("pause");       // Windows-specific command that tells platform to pause 
 program
    cout << endl;
   if (cin.get()) {        // If any key is entered, displayInput function is called
       displayInput();     
   }

}

void Bank::displayInput() {
   cout << "Initial Investment Amount: " << "$" << investment << endl;
   cout << "Monthly Deposit: " << "$" << deposit << endl;
   cout << "Annual Interest: " << interest << "%" << endl;
   cout << "Number of years: " << years << endl;
   system("pause");
   cout << endl;
   reportWithoutMonthlyPay();
}

void Bank::reportWithoutMonthlyPay() {
   year_numbers.resize(years);
   month_numbers.resize(12);
   interest = interest / 100;
   year_end_interest = 0;
   year_end_balance = investment;

   cout << "   Balance and Interest Without Additional Monthly Deposit   " << endl;
   cout << "=============================================================" << endl;
   cout << "Year    Year End Balance    Year End Earned Interest" << endl;
   cout << "-------------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
   for (int i = 0; i < year_numbers.size(); i++) {
       year_numbers[i] = i + 1;
       year_end_interest = 0;
       for (int j = 0; j < month_numbers.size(); j++) {
           monthly_interest = year_end_balance * (interest / (double)12);
           year_end_interest += monthly_interest; 
           year_end_balance += year_end_interest;
           month_numbers[j]++;
       }
       cout << year_numbers[i] << "        $" << fixed << setprecision(2) << 
     year_end_balance << "               $" << year_end_interest << endl;
    year_numbers[i]++;
   }
   cout << endl;
   system("pause");
   reportWithMonthlyPay();
  }

  void Bank::reportWithMonthlyPay() {
    year_numbers.resize(years);
    month_numbers.resize(12);
    year_end_interest = 0;
    year_end_balance = investment;
    cout << "   Balance and Interest With Additional Monthly Deposit   " << endl;
    cout << "==========================================================" << endl;
    cout << "Year     Year End Balance   Year End Earned Interest" << endl;
    cout << "----------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < year_numbers.size(); i++) {
       year_numbers[i] = i + 1;
       year_end_interest = 0;
       for (int j = 0; j < month_numbers.size(); j++) {
           year_end_balance += deposit;
           monthly_interest = year_end_balance * (interest / (double)12);
           year_end_balance += monthly_interest;
           year_end_interest += monthly_interest;
           month_numbers[j]++;
        }
       cout << year_numbers[i] << "        $" << fixed << setprecision(2) << 
    year_end_balance << "               $" << year_end_interest << endl;
    year_numbers[i]++;
   }
  }

int main()
 {
   Bank userInput;

   userInput.dataInput();
 }
```

Comment: X% annual interest is not the same as (X/12)% monthly interest. Also, you are adding the yearly interest to the balance in each month...

Comment: It looks like the first part of your comment was not the problem, but the second part was. Everything is working as it should now.

Comment: The first part will be relevant if you try to do more years or higher initial values.

Comment: The first will also be relevant depending on compounding period.  An annual rate of X% gives different results if compounded daily, weekly, fortnightly, monthly, bi-monthly, quarterly, .....

Comment: I don't know what you're talking about because I had divided annual interest by 12 for monthly interest in the for loops within both of my functions.